# laravel localhost project want to launch on live at slash folder like "domain_name.com/folder_name", getting misconfiguration error

Tags: php, laravel

laravel project working properly on localhost..

now I have uploaded it to live slash folder means like "domain_name.com/folder_name"

I have uploaded localhost project folder as it is (just .env parameters changes)..

Folder Structure:

```
Project Folder -
   app -
   bootstrap -
   ....
   ....
   public -
     ....
     ....
     .htaccess
     index.php
   ....
   vendor
   ....
   .env
   server.php
   ....
```

I have tried two way:

```
First Try-
1) server.php of root folder renamed to index.php
2) .htaccess moved from public folder to root folder
First Try resulting to "misconfiguration error"

Second Try-
1) .htaccess & index.php moved from public folder to root folder
2) In index.php..
     a) require __DIR__.'/../lara/vendor/autoload.php';
        changed to
        require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
     b) $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../lara/bootstrap/app.php';
        changed to
        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/bootstrap/app.php';
         Second Try resulting to "don't have permission to access /lara/ on this server"
```

In both trials, I have given full permission to required files, though not getting desired results

please suggest me proper configuration..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up virtual host and point it to public folder of your application.
Eg :

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/your-folder/public
    <Directory "/var/www/html/your-folder/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

allow overite for all permissions

Comment: its not expected way.. please suggest proper configuration